# NgbTypeahead set default value

Tags: angular, bootstrap-typeahead

How can I set a initial value in a NgbTypeahead formcontrol?

Parent.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formParent= this.fb.group({
            TypeAheadControl: ['', [Validators.required]],      
        });
    }
```

this control is used in a child component sending from parent component

```
@Input()
  public EIDControl: FormControl;
```

What is the correct form to initialize this kind formcontrol?

Thanks in advance.